# iOS app crash when keyboard showing on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an app which work perfectly on iPhone. But when i starting it on iPad and tap on UITextField it’s crash with error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x032a05e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02c1e8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x032414e6 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 246
    3   Parking                             0x002b0ccd -[UIView(Hackery) pd_swizzled_exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:] + 141
    4   UIKit                               0x020a89ef -[_UIBackdropView ensureProperSubviewOrdering] + 666
    5   UIKit                               0x020a810e -[_UIBackdropView updateSubviewHierarchyIfNeededForSettings:] + 127
    6   UIKit                               0x020a47dc -[_UIBackdropView setComputesColorSettings:] + 235
    7   UIKit                               0x01b1c87a -[UIKBBackdropView triggerUpdate:] + 400
    8   Foundation                          0x028f1bf9 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 40
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x032fc524 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0325400b _CFXNotificationPost + 2859
    11  Foundation                          0x0282b951 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98
    12  UIKit                               0x01e1cb1b -[UIInputViewTransition postNotificationsForTransitionEnd] + 1054
    13  UIKit                               0x0c69c453 -[UIInputViewTransitionAccessibility(SafeCategory) postNotificationsForTransitionEnd] + 51
    14  UIKit                               0x01e13138 __53-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) executeTransition:]_block_invoke1332 + 455
    15  UIKit                               0x019ef005 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 306
    16  UIKit                               0x019d8c6c -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 267
    17  UIKit                               0x019d8f58 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 80
    18  UIKit                               0x0c6a4b67 -[UIViewAnimationStateAccessibility(SafeCategory) animationDidStop:finished:] + 66
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00821a44 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 304
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0362b4b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0361975e _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x03305a5e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x032466bb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x03245ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x032458db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x03f7d9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x03f7d809 GSEventRun + 104
    28  UIKit                               0x0198cd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    29  Parking                             0x00073cad main + 141
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x038bd70d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I tried comment all my code to find a reason. Even created an empty view controller and add text field to it. But it’s didn't helped. Any idea?

Comment: This disturbs me: `UIView(Hackery) pd_swizzled_exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:`

Comment: The problem was in using pony debugger. It's strange, but it's cause an error. Thanks!

Comment: Then make an answer , if some1 will encounter it he will know what to do .

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question( So if you can do it please

Answer (score 1):

It is an [issue](https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger/issues/83) with PonyDebugger which has been fixed in the latest release. Use a version `>= 0.3.1`.

```
pod 'PonyDebugger', '~> 0.3.1'
```